# Do I have to show the .NET EULA if I am bootstraping my install

Tags: .net, wix, licensing, installation, .net-client-profile

I am using Wix 3.6 with a BootstraperApplication that will install the .NET 4.0 Client Profile if it is not detected on the users computer. I want to install .NET silently, and only show the progress in my managed UI.

I have a checkbox on my installer where the users must agree to my applications EULA, but haven't found a way to pull down the .NET EULA, or include it in my installer. I have noticed that ClickOnce projects find a way to bootstrap the .NET 4.0 install, but that breaks my desired UI flow.

Do I have to have users agree to the .NET license before I can bootstrap install it with my app? If I do, is there a way I can dynamically grab the .NET license if I detect I need to install it? And where would I pull it down from?

Comment: Google finds a thread about that here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/netfxsetup/thread/4a8af401-363f-47f6-9cc0-47232c66cb90

Comment: Note that [the text associated with the licensing tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info) says, "Do not ask for legal advice."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to show the .NET EULA.  You are only required to have a valid license to a .NET SDK (which you get with Visual Studio).  If you were required to show a EULA, the dotnetfx.exe would not have a silent install option.

The EULA for the .NET redistributable is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994405.aspx and makes no mention of having to display a .NET EULA.

Comment: Does the EULa apply in the case that we are redistributing the runtime? Surely there we are not the end user, so it is not for us to accept the EULA on their behalf? I have found information from MS that is quite specific that the EULA must be shown: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480235.aspx#isvdistmsdn_topic7
" Note that the redistribution license does not allow the ISV to alter  the installation experience of the runtime components (for instance,  it does not allow calling the runtime setup applications with the  silent option turned on)."